# Get file from content URI

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-storage

How can we parse CSV file from the content URI returned from ActivityResultContracts

```
   private val startActivity = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()){ uri ->
    uri?.let {
       
    }
}

 startActivity.launch(arrayOf("*/*"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uri?.let {
    var inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(fUri)
    //inputStream.read()
}
```

Comment: How do i parse the input stream to the csv file. inputStream.read() returns Int

Answer (score 0):

```
  fun readTextFile(source: Uri): String? {
        return try {
            val contentResolver = appContext.contentResolver
            val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(source)?: return null
            val byteArray = inputStream.readBytes()
            inputStream.close()
            byteArray
            String(byteArray)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw e
        }
    }
```